# How to body on click but exclude a particular element and its children using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

When attaching a click event listener to the body using javascript, how do you write a conditional(s) that only trigger if `e.target` is not the element that contains the class `active` or any of that elements children? There are children elements within `active` that need to be clickable. Similar to when you click anywhere on a modal it stays open, but anywhere else on the DOM it is removed?

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (!e.target ...) {
       // trigger functions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this effect is to listen for a click and then cycle upwards through the DOM from `e.target` all the way to `document.body`.

As you cycle upwards, check each element to see if it contains the class `.active`. If it does, you can end the function with a `break` statement.

This means you can still have children of `.active` which remain clickable and will respond to other `Event Listeners` firing other functions.

**Working Example:**

```js
const myFunction = (e) => {

  let containsActiveClass = false;
  let reviewNode = e.target;
  
  while (reviewNode.nodeName !== 'BODY') {
  
    if (reviewNode.classList.contains('active')) {
      containsActiveClass = true;
      break;
    }
    
    reviewNode = reviewNode.parentNode;
  }
  
  if (containsActiveClass === false) {
    window.alert('You clicked! (But not on .active or any of its child elements.)');
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: rgb(127, 127, 191);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  cursor: default;
}

.active,
.inactive {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 120px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.active div,
.inactive div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="inactive">Inactive
<div>Inactive Child</div>
</div>

<div class="active">Active
<div>Active Child</div>
</div>

<div class="inactive">Inactive
<div>Inactive Child</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match it with css selector

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(elem=>{
 console.log(elem.id, elem.matches('.active, .active *'))
})
```

```html
<div id=d1>
  <div id=d2 class=active>
    <div id=d3></div>
  </div>
  <div id=d4>
    <div id=d5></div>
    <div id=d6 class=active></div>
  </div>
</div>
```